# Load default android web browser

Tags: android, browser, android-intent

I am currently developing an android application. I want the user to select an item from a listview from and it loads the url that is assigned with the selected option in the default android browser instead of using a webview as that would mean that I would have to effectively make my own web browser.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Intent internet = new Intent(); 
internet.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
internet.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE); 
internet.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); 
startActivity(internet);
```